# java regex extract until special char

Tags: java, regex

```
String str = "Text0TEXT1.more text ";
String str = "Text0TEXT1(more text ";
String str = "Text0TEXT1{more text ";
```

If I have a line that it end could be several chars such as . or ( or { or ; how can I extract TEXT1 only ?

**Update**: There is Text 0 before text 1 and the special char may or may not exist

**Update 2**

```
String str = "Beginning text Text I want . Text I don't want"
String str = "Beginning text with numbers Text I want ( Text I don't want )"
String str = "Beginning text with numbers Text I want { Text I don't want }"
```

I need to extract "Text I want" but I get the rest of the text till the end . Special characters are . ( { :

Comment: You can split with a compiled pattern that includes these characters.

Comment: In regards to your edit, are you looking to get back `Text0TEXT1` or still only `TEXT1`?

Comment: are you trying to extract the first ALLCAPS word followed by a single digit before a special character?

Comment: @Alex not necessarily CAPS it is just phrase that I was able to extract . I need to stop when I found the special char

Comment: I'm assuming these aren't actual examples since finding TEXT1 would be too easy. Would you be able to give us actual examples of what you're looking for?

Comment: @Shaded TEXT1 could be any text that I am able to extract , my problem how to stop when I see the special char ?

Comment: `str.split("\\W+")[0]` should do it for you then

Comment: @Alex this will stop when found , which I need

Comment: updated my answer to include spaces

Comment: What is special char for you and what is not? Show us some real samples.

Comment: @M42 please check updated examples

Comment: @tnaser how do you differentiate `Beginning text` from `Text I want`? also, updated my answer with your latest examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z ]+[0-9]+ )?([a-zA-Z ,]+)
```

The text you want is in group 1.

**explanation:**

```
^                 : begining of string
  (?:             : start non capture group
    [a-zA-Z ]+    : one or more letter or space
    [0-9]+        : one or more digit
                  : a space
  )?              : end of group optional
  (               : start capture group 1
    [a-zA-Z ,]+   : one or more letter, sapce or coma
  )               : end of group
```

Comment: This will remove that last part of the str but the text I want can contains , also

Comment: @tnaser: Just add the allowed characters in the char class. See my edit.

Comment: Sounds good . I didn't fully understand it.The first part will accept any char expect what ?  How can I extract the text I want ? It contains pattern like "Text 1 text I want" or "Text 1 text needed" .

Comment: @tnaser: Sorry for late answer, see my edit for an explanation of regex

Answer (score 0):

```
str.split("[^\\w\\s]+")[0]
```

This will match all consecutive [a-zA-Z_0-9] characters and whitespaces from the beginning of the line

```
List<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
str.add("TEXT1.more text ");
str.add("TEXT1)more text ");
str.add("TEXT1}more text ");
str.add("Beginning text Text I want . Text I don't want");
str.add("Beginning text with numbers Text I want ( Text I don't want )");
str.add("Beginning text with numbers Text I want { Text I don't want }");
for(String s : str)
    System.out.println("input: [" + s + "], first word: " + s.split("[^\\w\\s]+")[0]);
```

produces:

```
input: [TEXT1.more text ], first word: TEXT1
input: [TEXT1)more text ], first word: TEXT1
input: [TEXT1}more text ], first word: TEXT1
input: [Beginning text Text I want . Text I don't want], first word: Beginning text Text I want 
input: [Beginning text with numbers Text I want ( Text I don't want )], first word: Beginning text with numbers Text I want 
input: [Beginning text with numbers Text I want { Text I don't want }], first word: Beginning text with numbers Text I want
```

Answer (score 0):

I've setup a simple example that will solve your regex by using positive lookahead matching regex:

```
[\w ]+(?=[.{(;])
```

The regex above will extract the part before the special characters.

Edit:

For the TEXT0 part is there a specific pattern for it?

Comment: No it could be any text , text 1 have special pattern . It begins with . "Text1 text I need"